# HAProxy Docker Container is Not able to load balance across my Cockroach DB docker containers using localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, haproxy, cockroachdb

I have a docker compose file that contains my HAProxy container and 3 Cockroach DB (CKDB) containers. All run with network mode host.

I am able to join the CKDB nodes using localhost and their associated ports, but my HAProxy container fails to access the CKDB nodes using "**localhost**". If I use the IP address of the host machine, it works.

Is this a constraint on HAProxy or could it be something wrong with my configurations?

Here's the HAProxy config file:

```
global
  maxconn 4096

defaults
    mode                tcp
    timeout connect     10s
    timeout client      1m
    timeout server      1m
    option              clitcpka

frontend ckdb_nodes
    bind *:26257
    option tcplog
    option httpchk GET /health?ready=1
    mode tcp
    use_backend ckdb_nodes

backend ckdb_nodes
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server cockroach1 localhost:26254 check port 8081
    server cockroach2 localhost:26255 check port 8082
    server cockroach3 localhost:26256 check port 8083

frontend ckdb_admin_ui
    bind *:8080
    option tcplog
    mode tcp
    use_backend ckdb_admin_ui

backend ckdb_admin_ui
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server cockroach1 localhost:8081 check
    server cockroach2 localhost:8082 check
    server cockroach3 localhost:8083 check
```

Here is the docker compose file:

```
services:
  ckdb-e1-haproxy:
    image: ${IMAGE_STAGING_E1_HAPROXY}:${BUILD_VERSION_STATIC}
    ports:
      - ${COCKROACH_E1_HAPROXY_PORT}:${COCKROACH_E1_HAPROXY_PORT}
      - ${COCKROACH_ADMIN_UI_E1_HAPROXY_PORT}:${COCKROACH_ADMIN_UI_E1_HAPROXY_PORT}
    network_mode: "host"
    container_name: ${PROJECT}_ckdb-e1-haproxy
    depends_on:
      - ckdb-e1-node1
      - ckdb-e1-node2
      - ckdb-e1-node3

  ckdb-e1-node1:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:${CKDB_VERSION}
    command: start --certs-dir=${CKDB_CONTAINER_HOST_DIR} --port=${STAGING_E1_NODE1_CKDB_APP_PORT} --http-port=${STAGING_E1_NODE1_CKDB_ADMIN_UI_PORT}
    ports:
      - ${STAGING_E1_NODE1_CKDB_APP_PORT}:${STAGING_E1_NODE1_CKDB_APP_PORT}
      - ${STAGING_E1_NODE1_CKDB_ADMIN_UI_PORT}:${STAGING_E1_NODE1_CKDB_ADMIN_UI_PORT}
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ${CKDB_STAGING_E1_CERTS_DIR}
        target: ${CONTAINER_CKDB_CERTS_PATH}
      - type: volume
        source: staging-app-db-data-e1-node1
        target: ${CONTAINER_CKDB_DATA_PATH}
    container_name: ${PROJECT}_ckdb-e1-node1
    network_mode: "host"

  ckdb-e1-node2:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:${CKDB_VERSION}
    command: start --certs-dir=${CKDB_CONTAINER_HOST_DIR} --port=${STAGING_E1_NODE2_CKDB_APP_PORT} --http-port=${STAGING_E1_NODE2_CKDB_ADMIN_UI_PORT} --join=localhost:${STAGING_E1_NODE1_CKDB_APP_PORT}
    ports:
      - ${STAGING_E1_NODE2_CKDB_APP_PORT}:${STAGING_E1_NODE2_CKDB_APP_PORT}
      - ${STAGING_E1_NODE2_CKDB_ADMIN_UI_PORT}:${STAGING_E1_NODE2_CKDB_ADMIN_UI_PORT}
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ${CKDB_STAGING_E1_CERTS_DIR}
        target: ${CONTAINER_CKDB_CERTS_PATH}
      - type: volume
        source: staging-app-db-data-e1-node2
        target: ${CONTAINER_CKDB_DATA_PATH}
    container_name: ${PROJECT}_ckdb-e1-node2
    depends_on:
      - ckdb-e1-node1
    network_mode: "host"

  ckdb-e1-node3:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:${CKDB_VERSION}
    command: start --certs-dir=${CKDB_CONTAINER_HOST_DIR} --port=${STAGING_E1_NODE3_CKDB_APP_PORT} --http-port=${STAGING_E1_NODE3_CKDB_ADMIN_UI_PORT} --join=localhost:${STAGING_E1_NODE1_CKDB_APP_PORT}
    ports:
      - ${STAGING_E1_NODE3_CKDB_APP_PORT}:${STAGING_E1_NODE3_CKDB_APP_PORT}
      - ${STAGING_E1_NODE3_CKDB_ADMIN_UI_PORT}:${STAGING_E1_NODE3_CKDB_ADMIN_UI_PORT}
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ${CKDB_STAGING_E1_CERTS_DIR}
        target: ${CONTAINER_CKDB_CERTS_PATH}
      - type: volume
        source: staging-app-db-data-e1-node3
        target: ${CONTAINER_CKDB_DATA_PATH}
    container_name: ${PROJECT}_ckdb-e1-node3
    depends_on:
      - ckdb-e1-node1
      - ckdb-e1-node2
    network_mode: "host"
```

Comment: I can tell you that it's a configuration problem, because I can happily run 3 cockroach nodes and haproxy all on localhost and have everything work. However, this isn't enough information to really tell what's wrong. If you can provide the full configuration of what is and isn't working, I can try to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @AlexRobinson thanks for the response I have added the haproxy config file and the docker compose with the ckdb nodes and ha proxy container.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my full configuration for reference:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  roachnet:
    driver: bridge

services:
  # CockroachDB Load Balancer
  crdb-lb:
    hostname: crdb-lb
    image: haproxy:2.0.7
    volumes: ['./crdb-lb.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro']
    networks: ["roachnet"]
    ports:
      - "26257:26257"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8081:8081"
    links:
      - roach1
      - roach2
      - roach3

  # CockroachDB default topology - 3 nodes
  roach1:
    # see https://hub.docker.com/r/cockroachdb/cockroach/tags
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:v19.1.5
    hostname: roach1
    networks:
      - roachnet
    volumes: ["./cockroach-data/roach1:/cockroach/cockroach-data"]
    command: "start --insecure --cache=.25 --max-sql-memory=.25"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 65535
        hard: 65535
  roach2:
    # see https://hub.docker.com/r/cockroachdb/cockroach/tags
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:v19.1.5
    hostname: roach2
    networks: ["roachnet"]
    volumes: ["./cockroach-data/roach2:/cockroach/cockroach-data"]
    command: "start --insecure --join=roach1 --cache=.25 --max-sql-memory=.25"
    depends_on: ["roach1"]
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 65535
        hard: 65535
  roach3:
    # see https://hub.docker.com/r/cockroachdb/cockroach/tags
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:v19.1.5
    hostname: roach3
    networks: ["roachnet"]
    volumes: ["./cockroach-data/roach3:/cockroach/cockroach-data"]
    command: "start --insecure --join=roach1 --cache=.25 --max-sql-memory=.25"
    depends_on: ["roach1"]
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 65535
        hard: 65535
```

And my **crdb-lb.cfg** which I map via Docker compose to **haproxy.cfg**:

```
global
    maxconn 4096
    nbproc 1
    nbthread 4

defaults
    mode                tcp
    # Timeout values should be configured for your specific use.
    # See: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4-timeout%20connect
    timeout connect     10s
    timeout client      30m
    timeout server      30m
    # TCP keep-alive on client side. Server already enables them.
    option              clitcpka

listen cockroach-db
    bind :26257
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk GET /health?ready=1
    server roach1 roach1:26257 check port 8080
    server roach2 roach2:26257 check port 8080
    server roach3 roach3:26257 check port 8080

listen cockroach-ui
    bind :8080
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk GET /health
    server roach1 roach1:8080 check port 8080
    server roach2 roach2:8080 check port 8080
    server roach3 roach3:8080 check port 8080

listen stats
    bind :8081
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /
```

Before connecting of course make sure that you create the user that you want to connect with. You can easily get a shell by doing `docker-compose exec roach1 ./cockroach sql --insecure` and then you can create your db and user from there.

```sql
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS myuser;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser;
```

Then in my Golang application I just connect by hitting `localhost` on port `26257` like this:

```golang
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgresql://myuser@localhost:26257/mydb?sslmode=disable")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error connecting to the database: ", err)
}
```